# Kafka Consumer (Java) polls 0 messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am seeing this issue in my Kafka Java client where the consumer stop consuming after polling a few messages. Its not that the consumer hangs. Its unable to find messages in the topic partitions and polls 0 message. I have 4 partitions configured for the topic and 2 consumers for the consumer group.

**Consumer Log:**

```
Thread-5:2016-05-11 at 07:35:21.893 UTC INFO  xxxxx.KafkaConsumerClient:71 pullFromQueue polled 0 messages from topic: test:[test-0, test-1] partition : []

Thread-5:2016-05-11 at 07:35:31.893 UTC INFO  xxxxx.KafkaConsumerClient:71 pullFromQueue polled 0 messages from topic: test:[test-0, test-1] partition : []

Thread-5:2016-05-11 at 07:35:41.893 UTC INFO  xxxxx.KafkaConsumerClient:71 pullFromQueue polled 0 messages from topic: test:[test-0, test-1] partition : []

Thread-5:2016-05-11 at 07:35:51.893 UTC INFO  xxxxx.KafkaConsumerClient:71 pullFromQueue polled 0 messages from topic: test:[test-0, test-1] partition : []
```

Here, the log suggests that this consumer is connected to partitions 0 and 1 but is unable to consumer any message.

**Consumer Offset:**

```
Group         Topic              Pid   Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner

test-consumer test                0   1147335         1150034         2699            none

test-consumer test                1   1147471         1150033         2562            none

test-consumer test                2   1150035         1150035         0               none

test-consumer test                3   1150031         1150031         0               none
```

Here this shows that my topic has 2699 and 2562 messages pending on partitions 0 and 1 respectively

Comment: I am not sure how to read the log. Why is "partition" empty, ie `[]`

Comment: when it polls something, it shows which partition it has consumed from. Currently its polling 0, hence partition block is shown empty.  polled 0 messages from topic: test:[test-0, test-1] partition : [] .. Here test-0 and test-1 are partitions the current consumer is subscribed to and [] is the partition it has consumed from (its 0 hence empty array)

Comment: @AnujModi did you figure out this?